# creating a web page that receives info from AWS IOT button

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, mqtt, aws-iot

i want to create a web page that gets information (MQTT message) from an AWS IOT button. I have a working, configured button and i already manged to make it send MQTT information to my computer. Now i want this MQTT information to be displayed on a web page. I want the web page to count the amount of the requests, and to display up to date information about the button (which is on every single MQTT message). How do i get started with this? I would appreciate any help. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `aws-sdk` for JS and `aws-iot-device-sdk` both from npm. Then, you can use something like this:

```
import { CognitoIdentityCredentials, CognitoIdentity, config, Credentials } from "aws-sdk";
import { device } from "aws-iot-device-sdk";

const mqttClient = null;
config.region = "us-east-1";
config.credentials = new CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:your-pool-id",
});
config.getCredentials((err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        const cId = new CognitoIdentity();
        cId.getCredentialsForIdentity({
            IdentityId: config.credentials.identityId
        })
            .promise()
            .then(result => {
                mqttClient = new device({
                    region: "us-east-1",
                    host: "your-iot-host.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                    clientId: "any client id",
                    protocol: 'wss',
                    accessKeyId: result.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                    secretKey: result.Credentials.SecretKey,
                    sessionToken: result.Credentials.SessionToken
                });
                mqttClient.on("connect", () => {
                    mqttClient.subscribe("some id for your web app - can be any string");
                });
                mqttClient.on("reconnect", () => {
                });
                mqttClient.on("message", (topic, payload) => {
                    console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, payload));
                    const message = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, payload));
                    console.log("message: " + message);
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Please note that the above code uses ES6 features. You might have to use some compiler like `babel` to convert it to ES5 which many more browsers support.